# Intercepting EventListener ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

I'm trying to extend the Button class and remove the default EventListener through the following:

```
removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
```

And then add something like this:

```
    protected function _clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
        Alert.show("Are you sure about this operation", "Alert", 3, this, execute);
        function execute(e:CloseEvent):void{
            if(e.detail == Alert.YES)
                super.clickHandler(event);
        }
    }
```

This way, I'll have a default component which will trigger a message alert with YES or NO option and prevent me from having to write that on every button that trigger the server. Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work that way.

1. Tried removing the default function and adding the one I wrote on listener;
2. Tried overriding clickHandler directly, also doesn't work;

---

Edit: Here is what I want: When the users click a button that will make a service call in my application, I always pop a window for him to tell me if he's sure of that. What I wanted was to build an automatic component for that, like this:

```
package screen{
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.Button;
import mx.events.CloseEvent;

public class CommonButton extends Button{
    public function CommonButton(){
        super();
        //removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler)
        //addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function (e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if(e.altKey == Keyboard.ENTER)
                dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
        });
    }

    private var _saveEvent:MouseEvent;
    override protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
        _saveEvent = event;
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        Alert.show("Are you sure about this operation", "Alert", 3, this, execute);         
    } 

    private function execute(e:CloseEvent):void{
        if(e.detail == Alert.YES)
            super.clickHandler(_saveEvent);
    }
}
}
```

And then:

```
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        private function test():void{
            //if the user clicked No, this method will never be called.
            Alert.show("You clicked YES");
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<screen:CommonButton click="test()" />
```

---

Final Edit with Solution:

```
package screen{
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.Button;
import mx.events.CloseEvent;

public class CommonButton extends Button{
    public function CommonButton(){
        super();
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function (e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if(e.altKey == Keyboard.ENTER)
                dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
        });
    }

    private var _stopProp:Boolean = true;
    override protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
        if(_stopProp){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation()
            Alert.show("Are you sure about this operation", "Alert", 3, this, execute);
        }else
            _stopProp = true;

    } 

    private function execute(e:CloseEvent):void{
        if(e.detail == Alert.YES){
            _stopProp = false;
            dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post the code that shows your attempt at overriding clickHandler?

Comment: Is flash.display.SimpleButton what your referring to? What functionality of it are you trying to alter with your override. Are you trying to intercept other subscribed event handlers with a dialog first?

Comment: I want to not allow the click method be called before the confirmation is made. Basically, I want to store the click method inside the class and force the ask for confirmation, if the user clicks YES, I instantly proceed with the original call. I did not wanted to do this using a different attribute, I actually wanted to keep using 'click'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why even bother with this? Just add your custom event handler to the extended component and allow the normal event handler to fire regardless. You can have multiple handlers registered to the same event. The only reason I could see this being an issue is if you were releasing this as a library and wanted to prevent the user from attach a click handler themselves, but you're not. You don't need to remove or stop the default click handler at all here.

EDIT: Here is an example of what the asker wants to happen here.

```
public class AButton extends Button
{
    private var stopProp:Boolean = true;

    public function AButton()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,this.clickHandlers);
    }

    private function clickHandlers( e:MouseEvent ):void{
        if ( stopProp ) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            trace( "clicked in button" );
            Alert.show( "Continue with event", "Warning!", Alert.YES|Alert.NO, null, this.closeHandler  );
        }
    }

    private function closeHandler( e:CloseEvent ):void {
        if ( e.detail == Alert.YES ) {
            this.stopProp = false;
            this.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent( MouseEvent.CLICK ) );
            this.stopProp = true;
        }
    }
}
```

That will stop the event from going any further if the `stopProp` property is true. Then it will prompt the user. If the user selects "Yes", it will set stopProp to false, re-dispatch a click event from the button, and reset stopProp to false for next time. If they select "No", nothing happens.

I made a quick prototype to test this and it definitely worked.

Comment: What I want is exactly what you described. I want to release it as library and the developer will define a click for the button. But before the click actually be called, I want to ask the user (not the developer) if he's sure of the action he selected. If he is sure of it, the click the developer defined will be made.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu See the code snippet I just added to my answer. This should do what you want. If not, I have completely misunderstood what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use stopImmediatePropagation() method of the Event class.

```
protected function _clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    Alert.show("Are you sure about this operation", "Alert", 3, this, execute);
    function execute(e:CloseEvent):void{
        if(e.detail == Alert.YES)
            super.clickHandler(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: StopImmediatePropagation did work and made the click method never be called, instead only the Alert with confirmation. But what did not work was the *super.clickhandler(event)*, which did not kept proceeding with the call.

Comment: The reason that did not work is because the clickHandler is just that: a clickHandler. It has internal functions it must run, but it does not dispatch an event itself. That click handler will run regardless of what you do, because your handler will run after the default handler. So by calling `super.clickHandler(event)`, you are essentially running the eternal click mechanisms twice when you don't need to do that.